# Data calculated per 100 inhabitants

Tags: dataset

I found data that indicate the vaccination coverage of a given vaccine in Italy in year 2014.
These data are calculated per 100 inhabitants and in %.

[image]

What does "per 100 inhabitants" mean?

If I wanted to compare this data with other data that are instead calculated for 1000 inhabitants, should I first process them?
If instead I wanted to compare them with the population of each region?

Thanks

Comment: I think, per 100 abitanti just means, that these are data in percent ("Percent" meaning "per 100" and "abitanti" meaning "not just adults").

Comment: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4Up1.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4Up1.png) what about this graph here , it surpasses the 100 people per hundred people , how it that possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It refers to proportion (in this case you can think it as a percentage, too) For example, first row-first column (96.21) means that for every 100 people, 96.21 have the polio vaccine. The interpretation is the same for the rest of data. If you multiply by 10, then you have 962.1 per 1000 inhabitants. Because of that, there's no need to make any further calculations: it's perfectly legitimate  to use the data shown in the table.

Comment: Proportion strictly refers to values on a scale from 0 to 1, just like the conventional expression of probability.